# Kmeans clustering identifying knowledge in R

Tags: r, k-means

I am new to R and the clustering world. I am using a shopping dataset to extract features from it in order to identify something meaningful.

So far I have managed to learn how to merge files, remove na., do the sum of errors squared, workout the mean values, summarise by group, do the K means clustering and plot the results X, Y.

However, I am very confused on how to view these results or identify what would be a useful cluster? Am i repeating something or missing out on something? I get confused with plotting X Y variables aswell.

Below is my code, maybe my code might be wrong. Could you please help. Any help would be great.

```
# Read file
mydata = read.csv(file.choose(), TRUE)

#view the file
View(mydata)

#create new data set
mydata.features = mydata

mydata.features <- na.omit(mydata.features)

wss <- (nrow(mydata.features)-1)*sum(apply(mydata.features,2,var))
for (i in 2:20) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata.features, centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:20, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata.features, 3) 
# get cluster means 
aggregate(mydata.features,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
# append cluster assignment
mydata.features <- data.frame(mydata.features, fit$cluster)

results <- kmeans(mydata.features, 3)

plot(mydata[c("DAY","WEEK_NO")], col= results$cluster
```

Sample data Variables, below are all the variables I have within my dataset, its shopping dataset collected over 2 years

PRODUCT_ID  - uniquely identifies each product
household_key - uniquely identifies each household
BASKET_ID   -  uniquely identifies a purchase occasion
DAY - day when transaction occured
QUANTITY - number of products purchased during the trip
SALES_VALUE - amount of dollar retailers receive from sales
STORE_ID - identifies unique stores
RETAIL_DISC - disccount applied due to manufacture coupon
TRANS_TIME  - time of day when the transaction occurred
WEEK_NO - week of transaction occurred 1-102
MANUFACTURER - code that links products with same manufacture together
DEPARTMENT  - groups similar products together
BRAND   - indicates private or national label band
COMMODITY_DESC  - groups similar products together at the lower level
SUB_COMMODITY_DESC - groups similar products together at the lowest level

Comment: You may be interested in the function `clusGap` in the `cluster` package. It computes a 'goodness of clustering' statistic for many possible values of k. Your question as it stands is not reproducible because you haven't provided sample data. Also, your question about how to identify a useful cluster is a complex, unanswered question in statistics and machine learning. Not really a programming question.

Comment: hi I have just added all the variables within my dataset. I am having trouble to understand what features can be used to identify something meaningful within the dataset?

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Data**

I put together some sample data, so I can help you better:

```
#generate sample data
sampledata <- matrix(data=rnorm(200,0,1),50,4)

#add ID to data
sampledata <-cbind(sampledata, 1:50)

#show data:
head(sampledata)
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.72859559 -2.2864943 -0.5408501  0.1564730    1
[2,]  0.34852943  0.3100891  0.6007349 -0.5985266    2
[3,] -0.04605026  0.5067896 -0.2911211 -1.1617171    3
[4,] -1.88358617  1.3739440 -0.5655383  0.9518367    4
[5,]  0.35528650 -1.7482304 -0.3871520 -0.7837712    5
[6,]  0.38057682  0.1465488 -0.6006462  1.3827544    6
```

I have a matrix with data points. Each data point has 4 variables (column 1 - 4) and an id (column 5).

**Apply K-means**

After that I apply the k-means function (but only to column 1:4 since it doesnt make much sense to cluster the id):

```
#kmeans (4 centers)
result <- kmeans(sampledata[,1:4], 4)
```

**Analyse output**

if i want to see what data point belongs to which cluster i can type:

```
result$cluster
```

The result will be for example:

```
[1] 4 3 2 2 1 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 2 1 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 2 4 4 2 4 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 4 1 1 1
```

This means that data point 1 belongs to cluster 4. The second data point belongs to cluster 3, and so on...
If I want to retrieve all data points that are in cluster 1, i can do the following:

```
sampledata[result$cluster==1,]
```

This will output a matrix, with all the values and the Data Point Id in the last Column:

```
            [,1]         [,2]       [,3]        [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  0.3552865 -1.748230422 -0.3871520 -0.78377121    5
 [2,]  0.5806156  0.479576142  1.1314052  1.60730796   14
 [3,]  1.1871472  1.280881477 -1.7227361 -0.89045074   22
 [4,]  0.8482060  0.726470349  0.6851352 -0.78526581   23
 [5,] -0.5324139 -1.745802580  0.6779943  0.99915708   24
 [6,]  0.2472263 -0.006298136 -0.1457003 -0.44789364   29
 [7,]  0.1412812 -0.247076976  0.9181507 -0.58570904   39
 [8,]  0.1859786 -1.768692166  0.5681229 -0.80618157   43
 [9,] -1.1577178 -0.179886998  1.5183880  0.40014071   45
[10,]  1.0667566 -1.602875994  0.6010581 -0.49514049   46
[11,]  0.2464646  1.226129859 -1.3628096 -0.37666716   48
[12,]  1.2660358  0.282688323  0.7650636  0.23442255   49
[13,] -0.2499337  0.855327072  0.2290221  0.03492807   50
```

If i want to know how many data points are in cluster 1, I can type:

```
sum(result$cluster==1)
```

This will return 13, and corresponds to the number of lines in the matrix above.

**Finally some plotting:**

First, lets plot the data. Since you have a multidimensional dataframe, and you can only plot two dimensions in a standard plot, you have to do it like this. Select the variables you want to plot, For example var 2 and 3 (column 2 and 3). This corresponds to:

```
sampledata[,2:3]
```

To plot this data, simply write:

```
plot(sampledata[,2:3], col=result$cluster ,main="Affiliation of observations")
```

use the argumemnt col (this stands for colors) to give the data points a color accordingly to their cluster affiliation by typing col= result$cluster

If you also want to see the cluster centers in the plot, add the following line:

```
+ points(result$centers, col=1:4, pch="x", cex=3)
```

The plot should now look like this (for variable 2 vs variable 3):

(The dots are the data points, the X´s are the cluster centers)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with the k-means function, and its hard to help without any sample data. Here however is something that might help:

*kmeans returns an object of class "kmeans" which has a print and a fitted method. It is a list with at least the following components:*

- **cluster:** A vector of integers (from 1:k) indicating the cluster to which each point is allocated.
- **centers:** A matrix of cluster centres.
- **totss:** The total sum of squares.
- **withinss:** Vector of within-cluster sum of squares, one component per cluster.
- **tot.withinss:** Total within-cluster sum of squares, i.e. sum(withinss).
- **betweenss:** The between-cluster sum of squares, i.e. totss-tot.withinss.
- **size:** The number of points in each cluster.
- **iter:** The number of (outer) iterations.
- **ifault:** integer: indicator of a possible algorithm problem – for experts.

more [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html).

You can access these components like this:
I.e. if you want to have a look at the clusters:

```
results$cluster
```

Or have more details about the centers:

```
results$centers
```

Comment: Hi @maRtin thank you for your answer, I have done that stage what you have mentioned, once I have ran my K means I have for instance 4 clusters, now I wish to retrieve all that data with assigned cluster number to it. Could you help how I can achieve that in R?

Comment: I added a new answer. I hope this help. However if you liked my answers, I would be happy about an upvote. Thx

Comment: sorry just saw this now, I was suppose to get an email notification every time someone writes an answer but I guess its not working. If you could allow me some time I want to analyse your answer and I would give you an update. Thank you :)

Comment: hey maRtin I just done everything you said above and I have managed to get some results with my own data, I want to find out the mean and standard deviation for each cluster, would you know how to do that?